# jQuery UI dialog: how to add overlay with `modal: false` option?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Is it possible to add overlay to dialog with `modal: false`? Maybe with the help of external class...

Really need it!

Thanks!

Comment: I am curious as to why would you not use the `modal:true` option?

Comment: Because when dialog height more than window height it blocks browsers scrollbar, and not modal state doesn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding a div as the first element of body and displaying it when you open the dialog box. Here is sample CSS for that div. This will create a div covering the entire page with black color an opacity 70%. You will have to adjust the z-index according to the z-index of the dialog and use the `open` event of jquery UI dialog to make this div visible.

```
.overlaydiv{ background-color: #000000; display: none; height: 100%; -moz-opacity: 0.7; opacity:.70; filter: alpha(opacity=70); left: 0%; position: fixed; top: 0%; width: 100%; z-index:1001; }
```

Make sure to add a div right after the opening  tag, else it would not cover the entire page.

```
<body>
<div class="overlaydiv"></div>
...
</body>
```